# Which manufacturers make/sell nested dice?

Tags: dice

By nested dice I mean a transparent hollow plastic n-sided die which contains a smaller n-sided die within.

I've searched on Chessex, Shapeways, and Q Workshop but either I've missed these offerings or they only sell complicated customizable n-sided dice.

For reference, the dice I'm talking about are along the lines of these:

[Nested D10](http://anterras.net/hobbies/pics/07.jpg) and [Nested D6](http://anterras.net/hobbies/pics/08.jpg)

I guess even purchasing two dice separately and assembling it myself is also a possibility, but I don't want to have to break the outer die just to get it apart.

Comment: I assume you don't have a reprap or equivalent 3d printer? :) Then the answer could be: "You!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they are [Koplow](http://www.koplowgames.com/page31.html) double dice.

Comment: Ah, those look like the ones I'm thinking of! Unfortunately, this doesn't look like it will suit my purposes. Specifically I'm looking to purchase nested d4 or nested d8 for a friend, whom already has a nested d6, d10, d12, and d20. That wasn't part of the question though, so I'll mark this as correct unless someone else posts a more complete nested polyhedral set.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t recall ever seeing a double d4 or a double d8. It’s not the same, but [here](http://www.gmdice.com/rpg-battle-dice-set) are d20s with other kinds of dice inside them. I guess one can use them to make to-hit and damage rolls at the same time in D&D.

Comment: Looks like d6, d10, d12, d20 is all they make (other than the dN-in-a-d20) https://www.thediceshoponline.com/dice-sets/483/Double-Dice

Answer (score 4):

You could always [3D print-on-demand your own custom ones](http://www.shapeways.com/).

That's what I did. They do a good job: [Thorn Dice](http://www.shapeways.com/model/126266/thorn-dice-set-with-decader.html).

Comment: Good answer. Welcome to the site, Xori, and thanks for giving us a link to the set you made.

Comment: Ouch. Very nice looking, but I fear for any tabletop onto which those are rolled!

Comment: We have those. They make a very satisfying "clunk" but they have not yet dented the table :)

Answer (score 0):

close to what you want, but as a gift idea: he may not have dice with *other* ones inside:
[Set of six 20 sided double dice matched with a D4, D6, D8, D10, D12, and D20.](http://www.scifigenre.com/itemDetail.aspx?nItemID=93958)